# Writing HTML to PDF file

Tags: iphone, html, xcode, pdf

I am trying to draw PDF from WORD(i.e .doc/.docx)file. For doing so, first i am loading the WORD file in UIWebView and then firing the following java script code in webViewDidFinishLoad to get contents of WORD file in HTML format.

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *)webView
  {
  NSString *wordDoctext = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document. body.innerHTML"];
  }

Now i want to write this HTML on PDF file in such a way that contents will look exactly like it appear in WORD file.

Answer (score 0):

We've a class "CGPDFDocument" which has a method "CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL".
Just provide the URL to above method as parameter......

Comment: Thanks for reply... CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL takes the URL of PDF document & it returns reference of PDF document.
What I want to know is how can I write HTML to PDF, So that resultant PDF & WORD file will be having same format (in terms of text style & formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have an answer, just curious if you have tried going straight from WORD to PDF without getting the HTML?

I am looking for a solution to show a WORD doc in iPhone, and be able to search and highlight.